# How to get full query text from performance_schema.threads?

Tags: mysql

According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/processlist-access.html#processlist-sources):

```
Access to the threads table does not require a mutex 
and has minimal impact on server  performance. The other
sources have negative performance consequences because they require a mutex.
```

So yes, I want to use threads table to examine running queries. The trouble is, the PROCESSLIST_INFO column does not contain the full query. It just contains a truncated version of the query. There is a flag viz performance_schema_max_sql_text_length which controls how many bytes are allocated for the SQL query. But it seems to affect the events_statements_history_long table. There is no change in the thread table output. Am I missing something?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The dba sister site of SO offers help in database internals questions like this one.

Comment: This is why cross-posting is bad.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the manual, ... (In other words, I did not test the following.)

It cannot be set dynamically; the manual is clear on that.  Instead, you should be able to set `performance_schema_max_sql_text_length` in the config file (`my.cnf`, etc).  That would require a restart of the server.

Note: The setting is limited to 1MB.

Comment: I did restart the server.